# How to reduce execution time for Java program?

Tags: java, performance

I have completed this code but it seems takes longer time than its permitted
code is to generate primes between multiple two  numbers.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class App {

    public static boolean isPrime(int p) {
        int i;
        boolean t = false;

        if (p == 2) {
            t = true;
        } else {
            for (i = 2; i < p; i++) {
                if (p % i == 0) {
                    t = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    t = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

    public static void numOfPrimes(int a, int b) {

        if (a >= 1 && a <= b && b <= 1000000000 && (b - a) <= 100000) {
            int i, prim = 0;
            boolean t = false;

            for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
                t = isPrime(i);

                if (t) {
                    System.out.println(i + "\n");
                    prim++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("bad input!!");
            System.out.println("inputs must be just like (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = 0, counter = 0;
        String str;

        try {
            str = br.readLine();
            t = Integer.parseInt(str);
            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (counter < t) {
                String s = br.readLine();
                arr.add(s);
                counter++;
                System.out.println("\n");
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < arr.size(); x++) {
                StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer(" "), s2 = new StringBuffer("");
                int q = 0, i, j;
                int num1, num2;

                for (i = 0; i < arr.get(x).indexOf(' '); i++) {
                    q++;
                    s1 = s1.append(arr.get(x).charAt(i));
                }

                String s5 = s1.toString();

                for (j = q + 1; j < arr.get(x).length(); j++) {
                    s2 = s2.append(arr.get(x).charAt(j));
                }

                String s6 = s2.toString();

                try {
                    num1 = Integer.parseInt(s5.trim());
                    num2 = Integer.parseInt(s6.trim());
                    App.numOfPrimes(num1, num2);
                    System.out.println("\n");
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

               //Will Throw exception!
               //do something! anything to handle the exception.
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("IO error ");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t4 - t1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more of a question for codereview and not for stackoverflow.

Comment: For starters, it's only necessary to iterate from 2 to sqrt(n) to check for primality. (And save the sqrt calculation.)

Comment: For starters, it's not necessary to double and triple space everything.

Comment: You don't need to double space all the code to make it look like you've done more work or written more LOC...We are not your boss/teacher, we won't reduce your paycheck for using single spaces.

Comment: "_how to reduce execution time for java program_" Try to come up with a different algorithm.

Comment: Thank you all..but I still do not know what should be done to reduce the execution time
i used sqrt (n) time, but still longer than the allowable limit..

Comment: I believe this problem statement is from SPOJ. which it seems you have completed in java and not matching timeline. as mentioned by dieend below, use different algorithms. you have used beginners logic.

Comment: Yes that's true..but I think the problem is not only in the algorithm of the primary number, but in the main() method.
I have commented the lines of the function numOfPrimes(int a, int b) and made it to print some strings only ,the execution time get of approximately 13 seconds while the maximum allowed is 3 seconds ..Could it be the use of Arraylist  instead of an String array is the reason? @Nachiket

Comment: arraylist internally uses array only but its a wrapper around array. so definitely that will hurt a bit. IMHO you should use more hw close language i.e. C and better algo. I have completed that one in C only. worked fine. some hints to optimize your code, avoid comparison by passing only matching values to function. optimize your input instead of passing all the values directly. this should reduce execution time by good amount. I should write it as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You used wrong algorithm here. Check out [Sieve of Erasthothenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) , and then modify it with your need. Moreover, you wanted to find prime number between 1 and 1x10^9, that's quite a lot. Maybe you need to elaborate why you need this.

Edit:

Cheating way: scrap the numbers from http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/liste_online_en.php instead of generating it.

Comment: as to why he needs it, i suspect it's homework :)

Comment: ps:  this particular sieve algorithm has it's limitations in java, as it's inherently array based, which criples your upper bound to Integer.MAX_INT.

Comment: @Matt well yeah, that's why "modify it with your need". With 10^9 array it's already uses almost 4GB of memory.

Comment: i didn't encounter any memory issues.  i just ran it with the default jdk settings for java 8.  it does tend to get slow between 10^8 and 10^9.  One could conceivably use BigInteger.nextProbablePrime() to do this as well, but that would be awefully slow.

Comment: @Matt Not exactly. You need one bit per potential prime (i.e., an odd number) and you can pack 64 of them into a `long`. This means something like `2 * 64 * Integer.MAX_VALUE` i.e., `2.7e11`. You could also use `long[][]`, but this is of no use as even filling the 1-dimensional array takes pretty long and needs 34 GB.

Comment: BTW, http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/liste_online_en.php may not be that straight forward to scrap.